# Reformat JSON string with php to morris charts formats

Tags: php, json, csv

I have the following json after converting a remote csv file to JSON

convert code for csv to json

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Token ****',
    'Accept-Version: ***',
));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
// Show me the result
//var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $data));
$encode = json_encode($array, true);

///////////////////////////////////////
```

It produces this:

```
[
"Timestamp",
"Point",
"Value",
"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
"ategho-leg_1-8",
"487.0",
"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
"ategho-leg_2-8",
"488.0",
"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
"ategho-leg_3-8",
"484.0",
"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
"ategho-temperature_long-8",
"466.0",
"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
"ategho-temperature_short-8",
"198.0",
"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
"ategho-leg_1-8",
"482.0",
"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
"ategho-leg_2-8",
"490.0",
"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
"ategho-leg_3-8",
"479.0",
"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
"ategho-temperature_long-8",
"464.0",
"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
"ategho-temperature_short-8",
"199.0",
null
```

]

And I want to turn it into data for use in morris charts, which wants the data in this format:

```
[
{"Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00", "Point":"ategho-leg_1-8", "Value":"487.0"}
]
```

I have searched stack and tried numersous things but I cannot get it to switch formats . I also tried stuff like this:

```
$new_final = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
    foreach($value as $sub_value) {
        $new_final[] = $sub_value;
    }
}

echo json_encode($new_final);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIt: the first answer gives me code like this :

```
{
  "Timestamp":[
     "2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "ategho-leg_3-8",
     "484.0"
  ],
  "Point":[
     "2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "ategho-temperature_long-8",
     "466.0"
  ],
  "Value":[
     "2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "ategho-temperature_short-8",
     "198.0"
  ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to process directly data from csv without pre-encoding in JSON.
BTW, this will works:

```
$data = json_decode( $json );

$result = array();
for( $i = 3; $i< count( $data ); $i=$i+3 )
{
    $result[] = array
    (
        'Timestamp' => $data[$i],
        'Point'     => $data[$i+1],
        'Value'     => $data[$i+2]
    );
}

echo json_encode( $result );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/NC2lM)**</kbd>

Basically, you need a for()` loop that start from 3rd item and that repeat each 3 items, then you can add to main array an associative array with your *morris chart* format.

In your example last JSON item is Null, so you have to decide if `unset()` it or if `unset()` last element of `$result` before converting to JSON.

---

#### Edit:

With modified question, you can process your array in this way:

```
$result = array();
for( $i = 1; $i < count( $array ); $i++ )
{
    $result[] = array
    (
        'Timestamp' => $array[$i][0],
        'Point'     => $array[$i][1],
        'Value'     => $array[$i][2]
    );
}
echo json_encode( $result );
```

Check **before** if the `Null` issue persists.

**Please note** that `for()` loop start from 1 to avoid header inclusion. If you doesn't have heads, you have to start loop form 0.

Comment: sorry im confused, is this processing csv directly like you said or is the code above for my current setup where i already encoded it to json. OK it for the code i have, but it outputs it wrong still, close though

Comment: You say “I have the following json after converting...”, so this code start decoding JSON, but why csv => array => json => array => process => final json? You can do directly csv => array => process => final JSON. I've been clear?

Comment: hi fusion. I am happy to edit the csv directly first before converting to json, if you show me how. I updated my answer to show what your code outputs, close but not exactly

Comment: Error: array size isn't a multiple of 3 (look at the trailing `null`). Should be smth like `$i < intval(count( $data ) / 3) * 3` or `for ($i = 3, $c = intval(count( $data ) / 3) * 3; $i < $c; $i += 3)`

Comment: I don't understand your edit. If it is the result of csv, how the JSON conversion can be like the example? BTW, the core of if the `for` loop, then you can adapt it like you prefer.

Comment: demo produces redundant `{"Timestamp":null,"Point":null,"Value":null}` because of trailing `null` in source array. That's what I'm pointing at.

Comment: @ankhzet sorry I think to respond to OP LOL. I have write about this on my answer: read it until the end. Sorry again for previous comment.

Comment: @ankhzet BTW, I can't see the error in the demo. Do you use PHP 7?

Comment: No, it's only that _eval.in_ don't output Notices

Comment: From my viewpoint, `unset` is unefficient at this point, better to keep source data array immutable. Also, code will generate notice about accessing array elements beyound that `null`, that will be treated as runtime error with corresponding error level of notice+ on most PHP versions, iirc.

Comment: @ankhzet BTW, the example provided is wrong, I guess, so also the answer! :( That is life!

Comment: ... or OP just tried to inject your's solution somewhere in his own `for - for` code...

Comment: i dint, i took my csv that i converted to json and used his code and that result i got is above in my answer lol. Ill post more code

Comment: @keaner, have you looked at demo provided by @fusion3k? It outputs exactly what you asking, no? Just use `$array` instead of `$data` and skip `$data = json_decode( $json );` entirely as you already decoded that csv to php object.

Comment: Dear @keaner if you use your code the JSON is not like in the example, if something like `[["Timestamp","Point","Value"],["2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00","ategho-leg_1-8","487.0"],......]` Also, in your code you don't process the JSON, but the array from csv

Comment: @ankhzet i have looked, i posted what his code spits out above, its not what im looking for. If i use $array i get:
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given i

Comment: @fusion3k that did it, fusion, thanks you very much, and others for their help.