# Group/combine json array by key

Tags: php, json, csv

How might I turn this (the full json is like below but every 5 minutes a new time stamp comes). I pull a full days worth of data at a time

```
[
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_1-8",
  "Value":"487.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_2-8",
  "Value":"488.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_3-8",
  "Value":"484.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-temperature_long-8",
  "Value":"466.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-temperature_short-8",
  "Value":"198.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_1-8",
  "Value":"487.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_2-8",
  "Value":"488.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_3-8",
  "Value":"484.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-temperature_long-8",
  "Value":"466.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-temperature_short-8",
  "Value":"198.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":null,
  "Point":null,
  "Value":null
}
]
```

Into this:

```
[
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "ategho-leg_1-8" : "487.0",
  "ategho-leg_2-8" : "488.0",
  "ategho-leg_3-8" : "484.0",
  "ategho-temperature_long-8" : "466.0",
  "ategho-temperature_short-8" : "198.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:45:00+00:00",
  "ategho-leg_1-8" : "487.0",
  "ategho-leg_2-8" : "488.0",
  "ategho-leg_3-8" : "484.0",
  "ategho-temperature_long-8" : "466.0",
  "ategho-temperature_short-8" : "198.0"
}
]
```

This is what i have tried but it doesn't work

```
 $datas = json_decode($morris, true);
$out = [];

foreach($datas as $element) {
    $out[$element['Timestamp']][] = ['Date' => $element['Timestamp'], 
  'Point' => $element['Point'], 'Value' => $element['Value']];
 }

$thing = json_encode($out);
```

outputs:

```
{
"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00":[
  {
     "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "Point":"ategho-leg_1-8",
     "Value":"487.0"
  },
  {
     "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "Point":"ategho-leg_2-8",
     "Value":"488.0"
  },
  {
     "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "Point":"ategho-leg_3-8",
     "Value":"484.0"
  },
  {
     "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "Point":"ategho-temperature_long-8",
     "Value":"466.0"
  },
  {
     "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
     "Point":"ategho-temperature_short-8",
     "Value":"198.0"
  }
 ],
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
foreach ($datas as $element) {
    $out["Timestamp"] = $element["Timestamp"];
    $out[$element["Point"]] = $element["Value"];
}
```

I took your data:

```
$r = '[
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_1-8",
  "Value":"487.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_2-8",
  "Value":"488.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-leg_3-8",
  "Value":"484.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-temperature_long-8",
  "Value":"466.0"
},
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00",
  "Point":"ategho-temperature_short-8",
  "Value":"198.0"
}
]';
$datas = json_decode($r, true);
$out = [];

foreach ($datas as $element) {
    $out["Timestamp"] = $element["Timestamp"];
    $out[$element["Point"]] = $element["Value"];
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($out),'</pre>';
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [Timestamp] => 2016-03-11T14:40:00+00:00
    [ategho-leg_1-8] => 487.0
    [ategho-leg_2-8] => 488.0
    [ategho-leg_3-8] => 484.0
    [ategho-temperature_long-8] => 466.0
    [ategho-temperature_short-8] => 198.0
)
```

This means that you give not enough info.

Comment: outputs: {"Timestamp":null,"ategho-leg_1-8":null,"ategho-leg_2-8":null,"ategho-leg_3-8":null,"ategho-temperature_long-8":null,"ategho-temperature_short-8":null,"":null} .  Close but not quite

Comment: I removed extra `$element`. Check now.

Comment: that fills in the values once,doesnt repeat for all the data. The "Timestamp" reads null and at the end ":null is still there

{"Timestamp":null,"ategho-leg_1-8":"490.0","ategho-leg_2-8":"492.0","ategho-leg_3-8":"488.0","ategho-temperature_long-8":"460.0","ategho-temperature_short-8":"72.0","":null}

Comment: ill look again but I cant see any error in the data i have given you. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I have added more code to the question if you want to look again.

Comment: @keaner you persevere with [sloppy questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947207/reformat-json-string-with-php-to-morris-charts-formats): u_mulder answer is correct, it is your sample code/desired result that is wrong (before editing). You have to pay attention on asking. I apologize if I'm a bit rude.

Comment: @fusion3k I'm not going to post 2000 lines of json in a question man. But thanks for your input and help on the other question

Comment: @keaner There are no reasons to post 2000 lines: it's enough your edited post, baby